# Can I make a parent page of the blog and have it display a paragraph/thumbnail of certain entries?

Tags: blog, thumbnails

WP 3.2.1

The title just about says it all.  I'd like to make a parent page of the blog that will dynamically show a little teaser of certain entries (either the most recent or random, depending on what my client wants).  Is something like this possible?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to display some posts but not have it function like the blog (with the prev/next links) then this should do the trick.

```
<?php global $post; $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'post_type' => 'post', ); $myposts = get_posts( $args ); foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    [act like it's the loop]
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So then you could do something like...

```
<?php global $post; $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'post_type' => 'post', ); $myposts = get_posts( $args ); foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { echo '<div class="featured-thumbnail">'; the_post_thumbnail(); echo '</div>'; } ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If I understand what you're wanting to accomplish correctly, then this'll do it.